# Sending form-data in a POST request in golang

Tags: http, go, post

I'm trying to send form-data by making a post request. The api works fine (I've tested on postman), but I'm not sure why I'm having trouble to do it in golang. The form-data contains a task field and a file field. But if I do the following I get Bad Request. Any ideas why I might be getting this? Thanks in advance.

```
// Create new buffer and writer
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
w := multipart.NewWriter(buf)


// read data from file
var fdata []byte
if fd, e := os.Open(pdf); e != nil {
    log.Fatal(e)        
} else {
    fd.Read(fdata)
}
        
// create file field and write
part, err := w.CreateFormFile("file", pdf) 
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
part.Write(fdata)



// create the task field and write
part, err = w.CreateFormField("task") 
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

part.Write([]byte(os.Getenv("task")))

w.Close()

// Create a new request
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", fmt.Sprintf("https://%v/v1/upload",os.Getenv("server")), buf)


// Set content type header
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")


// Send the request
client := &http.Client{}
    
resp, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()


// other stuff
```

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of `buf` to see if the body data makes sense?

Comment: - Yeah I checked buf but it doesn't make much sense. Its just a slice of bytes

- I added that line but it still doesn't work

Comment: Btw, pdf is a string containing the pdf's name. It is in the current directory. In this case, say "q1.pdf"

Comment: Yep did that. Still the same sadly

Comment: It's not "just a slice of bytes". It's UTF-8 encoded text, just like `string` except that a `[]byte` is modifiable and `string` is read-only. But in this case, `bytes.Buffer` even has a method `String()` that returns the contents of the buffer as a string, and you can print that.

Comment: I did fmt.Println(*buf) and got {[ ] 0 0}. Possibly this means that the write doesn't really work?

Comment: Yeah I got it maybe. The fix was to define fdata with fdata := make([]byte, size)